# I want to modify the code so that macro runs as soon as the workbook is opened

Tags: excel, vba

The macro is about locking columns containing all dates except column with today's date. I have coded it in each sheet and is exactly similar in all the sheets. Macro runs when the data in any cell is changed. But I want macro to run when the workbook is opened.

I tried to code it in 'this workbook' but I can not figure out how to do it. I also tried to do it in 'module' but could not.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
  'vps
  Dim x As Long
  x = 7
  ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123456"
  ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Locked = False
  Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(5, x))
    If Cells(5, x) <> Date Then
      Columns(x).Locked = True
    End If
    x = x + 1
  Loop
  ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="123456"
  End Sub
```

I want the macro to run when the workbook is opened and not only when the data in cell is changed.

Comment: Have you tried putting it in the Workbook_Open() event in ThisWorkbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Lock Cells on Workbook Open

### Features

- To run the following (or any) macro when a workbook opens, you have
  to use its Workbook_Open event. In VBA double-click ThisWorkbook. In
  the first drop down choose Workbook and in the second choose Open.
- For each worksheet in the workbook containing this macro, unprotects
  it and unlocks all cells. Then checks a specified row range for dates
  and locks cells of entire columns where today's date was not found.
  Finally protects the worksheet.
- Additionally the Interior color will be different in cells where
  today's date was found.

### Links

[Workbook Download (Dropbox)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a659g68lk31vmg6/i-want-to-modify-the-code-so-that-macro-runs-as-soon-as-the-workbook-is-opened_54356416.xls?dl=0)

### The Code

**Standard Module e.g Module1**

```
Sub ProtectPrevious()

    Const cRow As Long = 5        ' Date Row Number
    Const cFirstC As Variant = 7  ' First Column Letter/Number e.g. 7 or "G"
    Const cToday As Long = 6      ' Today Cell ColorIndex e.g. 6 is Yellow
    Const cDays As Long = 15      ' Other Days ColorIndex e.g. 15 is some Gray

    Dim ws As Worksheet   ' Current Worksheet
    Dim LastC As Long     ' Last Column Number
    Dim j As Integer      ' Column Counter

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            ' Prepare for processing.
            .Unprotect Password:="123456"
            .Cells.Locked = False
            ' When there is no data in Date Row, continue with next worksheet.
            If .Rows(cRow).Find("*", .Cells(cRow, _
                    .Columns.Count), -4123, , 1) Is Nothing Then Exit For
            ' Calculate Last Column Number
            LastC = .Rows(cRow).Find("*", , -4123, , 1, 2).Column
            ' Remove formatting from other day(s) in Date Row.
            With .Range(.Cells(cRow, cFirstC), .Cells(cRow, LastC))
                .Interior.ColorIndex = cDays
            End With
            ' Loop through columns: from First Column to Last Column.
            For j = cFirstC To LastC
                If .Cells(cRow, j) <> Date Then
                    .Columns(j).Locked = True
                  Else
                    ' Apply formatting to 'today' in Date Row.
                    With .Cells(cRow, j)
                        .Interior.ColorIndex = cToday
                    End With
                End If
            Next
            .Protect Password:="123456"
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

**ThisWorkbook**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ProtectPrevious
End Sub
```

Comment: This code works. But when I open the excel file, it seems that all the worksheets are processed first and the screen acts as if something is wrong(1st worksheet opens and then closes, 2nd worksheet opens and then closes and so on...) before becoming stable. And after I save it and open the file again there is no such issue. Can I know the reason why this is happening.

Comment: @Ashul garg: It might be connected to ScreenUpdating which you can suppress by adding **Application.ScreenUpdating = False** before the For Each Loop and enable with **Application.ScreenUpdating = True** after the For Each Loop.